# Form Validation in Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, coldfusion

i am trying to validate my form so it doesnt accept empty fields.
You can see i have tried to do validation on the "Country" using the 'required' property but that doesnt work....

I only want validation done on certain fields: Country, Address, City and ReceptionNumber

Here is my code for the form:

```
<head>

    <title>Office Location Entry Form</title>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <cfinclude template="CheckUserLogin.cfm">

</HEAD>


<body background="FFFFFF" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <P class="paratitle"><br> Country Offices Entry Form <BR>
    <P class="normal">Please fill in as many fields as possible. Please include the country dial code when entering phone or fax numbers.</p>

<!--- Entry form --->
<FORM name="officeLocations" action="officeLocations_EntryAction.cfm" method="post" onSubmit="return ValidateInput(this);">

    <TABLE>
        <!--- Field: office_locations.Country --->
        <TR>
        <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Country </TD>
        <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <input type="text" name="Country" size="30" maxlength="510" class="input" required="yes" message="You must enter a first country."> 
    </TD>
    </TR>


    <!--- Field: office_locations.address --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Address</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="address" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.address2 --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Address 2</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="address2" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.address3--->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Address 3</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="address3" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.address5--->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Address 4</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="address4" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.address4 --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> City</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="city" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.postcode --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Postal code</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="postcode" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.receptionnumber --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Reception number</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="receptionnumber" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.mainnumber --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Main number</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="mainnumber" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>

    <!--- Field: office_locations.faxnumber --->
    <TR>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal"> Fax number</TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="normal">

        <INPUT type="text" name="faxnumber" size="30" value="" maxLength="510" class="input">

    </TD>
    </TR>


    <INPUT type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<CFOUTPUT>#DateFormat(Now())#, #TimeFormat(Now())#</CFOUTPUT>" size="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="username" value="<CFOUTPUT>#Session.FirstName# #Session.LastName#</CFOUTPUT>" size="">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="NTusername" value="<cfoutput>#Session.NtUserName#</cfoutput>" size="">
</TABLE>
<P>
<input type="image" src="IMAGES/AddItButton.gif" align="absmiddle">

</FORM>

</body>



</html></HTML>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the `<input>` tags to be `<cfinput>`, and for this to be a `<cfform>`? As far as I can tell HTML 5 has a `required` attribute on `<input>`, but no `message`. And HTML 4 has neither. But both are attributes of `<cfinput>`..?

Comment: Oh, and you just shouldn't be using `<cfform>` and `<cfinput>` anyhow. Do the job properly with Javascript (and matching server-side validation).

Comment: Yes thank you, i managed to get it working using <CFFORM> and <CFINPUT>

Comment: post that as your answer so i can mark it as answered. cheers

Comment: NO...do not use `cfform` and `cfinput` as they will only cause issues down the road. Look into using ValidateThis, it is a fantastic validation library for ColdFusion.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean for you to actually *use* `<cfform>` and `<cfinput>`, I was just clarifying what you were asking. Using those tags is not part of any answer.

Comment: @ScottStroz do you have a link to ValidateThis ?

Comment: http://www.validatethis.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested I am posting this as an answer, but **I cannot stress enough** that this approach is a very poor one. It does, however, answer your question.

From the comments attached to the question:

> Do you mean the `<input>` tags to be `<cfinput>`, and for this to be a
>   `<cfform>`? As far as I can tell HTML 5 has a required attribute on
>   , but no message. And HTML 4 has neither. But both are
>   attributes of `<cfinput>`..? 
>        Oh, and you just shouldn't be using `<cfform>` and `<cfinput>` anyhow. Do the job properly with Javascript (and matching server-side
>   validation).

Comment: thanks for your help, this wasnt my code so i cannot change the structure of it. i just had to add the Validation....